# Are variables in list comprehensions immutable?

Tags: haskell

Are variables in list comprehensions immutable?

```
[x + 1 | x <- [1,2,3,4,5]]
```

For instance, in the above example, `x` seems to change it's value. Is this what is really happening, or is something more complicated at work here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are no variables in Haskell, only values bound to names.

What a list comprehension like this will get turned into is actually monadic list code:

```
y = [x + 1 | x <- [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
y = do
    x <- [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    return (x + 1)
```

Then this further gets reduced to using `>>=`:

```
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] >>= (\x -> return (x + 1))
```

And then we can look at the definition for the `Monad` instance for `[]`:

```
instance Monad [] where
    return x = [x]
    list >>= f = concat (map f list)
    -- uses the `concatMap` function in the actual definition
    -- where `concatMap f list = concat (map f list)`
```

So replacing `return`:

```
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] >>= (\x -> [x + 1])
```

And then `>>=`:

```
y = concat (map (\x -> [x + 1]) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Now we can reduce it:

```
y = concat [[1 + 1], [2 + 1], [3 + 1], [4 + 1], [5 + 1]]
y = concat [[2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]
y = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

So as you can see, it's not that `x` is a variable that changes values, `x` becomes the argument to a lambda function that is then mapped across the target list.

Comment: Excellent answer, but two nitpicks: (a) "values bound to names" is what variables are in mathematics; saying that Haskell has no variables I think can only create confusion; (b) as I understand it, the compiler does not actually turn list comprehensions into monadic code; basically, it skips the steps in your answer that involve `do`, `>>=` and `return`. Which is completely equivalent to what you show.

Comment: @LuisCasillas It's hand-wavy, for sure.  What GHC will actually desugar this to is a customized `map` function of `f = \ys -> case ys of { [] -> []; (x:xs) -> (x + 1) : f xs`, then apply that to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, but the basic concept is the same.  I imagine there's some optimizations in there for simple cases like this, but in general I think it's fair to say that GHC does this kind of de-sugaring, even if it's not doing this exact kind of desugaring.

Comment: @LuisCasillas And I think it's correct to say that Haskell doesn't have variables in the sense that Python has variables.  People always bring up `IORef`s and the like, but those still aren't variables, in order to get a value from them or into them, you perform an IO action, you aren't actually modifying the reference itself.  Once a name is bound in Haskell, you can't re-bind it later.  That name may take on different values in different contexts, but it is not mutable, and therefore does not vary and can not meet the basic requirement of being a variable.

Comment: @bheklilr: According to this terminology, ML (including OCaml and Standard ML) also doesn't have variables? And in other languages when you declare a `const` or `final` variable, it's not a variable? I would rather just call it a constant variable, or a variable that cannot be assigned to.

Comment: @newacct I would say colloquially they're called variables, but I try hard to keep my terminology straight.  In Haskell, I do my best to say "identifiers" or "names", and in langauges that have `const` or `final` keywords, I try to remember to call them "constants", since that's what they are.  Using the word "variable" everywhere makes this generally easier, but it can lead to confusion in languages that don't have C-like variables.